# Migrating Stored Procedures with Flyway

Tags: database, migration, flyway

How should procedural database code like stored procedures be managed with a database migration tool like Flyway?

Unlike DDL I would not want to see changes to a stored procedure stored within multiple database migration files.  How can procedural code be managed within a single file under source control, but also take advantage of database migrations with a tool like Flyway?

Comment: I created a very similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839666/flyway-strategy-for-migrating-frequently-changing-functions-stored-procedures) given this is 18months old and a major release has been published since.

Answer (score 13):

There is no special construct in the framework to deal with this. Mainly because I haven't figured out a way to do this that pleases me.

**Update:** Repeatable scripts are now fully supported as of Flyway 4.0. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#repeatable-migrations

Comment: Any closer to a suggested approach given the 3.0 release? I've re-asked this question [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839666/flyway-strategy-for-migrating-frequently-changing-functions-stored-procedures)

Answer (score 3):

What we do is:

1. Have a complete CREATE OR REPLACE Flyway script for stored procedures whenever they change.
2. Store each of the stored procedures in a separate area in source control, so that changes are tracked and differences are computable.

Not a great solution, and a pain to remember each time, but it gets past some of the limitations of the tool.