# How to avoid code duplication for non-data structures (views, stored procedures etc)

Tags: flyway

My project contains a lot of objects like views and stored procedures which are being changed quite frequently. Now I have to create new SQL script on every update which contains complete source code of changed objects despite I've actually changed only few rows. It leads to massive code duplication and I also found it difficult to review these changes.

I'd like to have only one actual version of SQL script for every object like view or procedure and recreate these objects every time I redeploy the database. As result I could change existing source file (like in Java or C programming) instead of creating a new update every time I need to alter view or procedure.

Is there a possibility to execute some scripts every time I migrate the database with Flyway?

Comment: i can not understand this ...

Comment: Tushar can you please explain what's not clear and I'll try to provide more details

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that got so many downvotes, it's a perfectly understandable and valid question.   Perhaps it's because it closely resembles this open question: 
[Migrating Stored Procedures with Flyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823318/migrating-stored-procedures-with-flyway)

We are actually starting to push against this issue now.  We've been using flyway for development and testing (and love it). But we've come to a point where we're starting to have to use procs/triggers/views (p/t/v's) and the fundamental disconnect between how we did it before, and how we must use flyway, is starting to be a strain.

Before, for a given database object (let's say it's a procedure), there'd be one source file. And if you needed to change the proc 'n' times, there would be 'n' versions of the same file in your VCS.  Diff tools work great, IDE's all understand this, merges detect when two developers working in separate branches make changes to the proc, etc, etc.  You know, old school.

But with flyway, any one proc with 'n' changes is now scattered across 'n' files.  Instead of "one object in one file with 'n' versions", you have "one objecct in 'n' files with one change each".  I now need to do a text search in my IDE for any instance of "proc_name" if I want to know the history of changes to the proc. The VCS knows nothing about it. Devs can each make a migration in their own branches that succeed when each is deployed, but leave the proc with a missing update.

I'm not saying any of this to complain about flyway, and I fully realize it's not a simple area.  I'd almost say it's unsolveable (by flyway).

We're scheming how to handle this problem, and I'd be very interested to know how others have handled it.

Answer (score -1):

Repeatable migrations are supported by Flyway 4.0, now.
Just add sql files starting with "R" without any version information to your migration folder:

R__Blue_cars.sql

You have to ensure, that the script could be repeatable migrated. 
This is usually done by "CREATE OR REPLACE" clauses in your DDL statements.

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/repeatable