# Flyway: Strategy for migrating frequently changing functions / stored procedures

Tags: postgresql, flyway

**My question is, has anyone found a satisfactory formula for migration large and frequently changing stored procedures?**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823318/migrating-stored-procedures-with-flyway) touches on it and has a response from the Flyway author but it's been over a year and a major release with exciting new framework hooks has since been published.

I've added a more thorough description of the problem and my current solution to [this flyway github issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/819) but I thought I'd reach out to a wider audience. As described, I have a working solution but has inelegant aspects to it.

I'm wondering if MigrationResolvers or FlywayCallbacks can be put to good use here?

Comment: have queried similar in https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1107 and http://forum.liquibase.org/#Topic/49382000001383021

Comment: Liquibase has a pretty good solution for this: the changeSet only includes an external script file and is marked as "run on change". So each time the included file has changed (based on the MD5 hash) Liquibase will run it - this requires that the file can always be run successfully (so it's only usable with "create or replace" types of scripts) - maybe Flyway has something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Repeatable Migrations!](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/using-repeatable-migrations-to-manage-data-190578952.html)

Purpose built for this situation, did not exist at time of asking in the 3.x release.

Comment: One concern: say there are 106 versioned migrations. There is one “repeatable” migration with all of the stored procedures. 100 of the versioned migrations have been run on some installation. Versions 102 rely on an old procedure definition. 103–106 rely on the most up to date procedure definition. How do you deal with that?